# I need $\frac{d}{du}\frac{\partial F}{\partial v'}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, calculus-of-variations

[image]
[image]

[image]
I find that

[image]

I have been several days without any effective result trying to find the derivative with respect to $ u $
can you help me find it?
i.e I need $\frac{d}{du}\frac{\partial F}{\partial v'}$

[image]